# How to stop the execution of a session of wxmaxima by command?

Tags: wxmaxima

how are you?.

I'm interested in stopping the execution of the wxmaxima session conditionally, this is by example using an if like follows

```
if(a > b)
    then "stop"
else "continue
```

I want to completelly stop the wxmaxima session on the line `then "stop"` to wait for the user to do something but I used the `break` instruction, then the message of a breakpoint reached is shown but the session continues to the end of the lines no matter what, a `go` to label instruction doesn't help either.

What can I do here?. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: When I try it, with `break("something")` within a function, it seem to work as expected -- it stops within the function, and then `exit;` allows the function to continue. If you're seeing something else, my advice is to post the exact code you are trying.

Comment: Hi @Robert Dodier, the code that I did has been erased last week, what I need is exactly the opossite to what your doing, I need precisselly to totally stop the execution of maxima, for example, I do a matrix calculation and adter that I need to stop there to see the result and to continue only if I want.